# Перегрузка оператора == и шаблоны

Tags: c++, шаблоны-с++, перегрузка-операторов

Почему присутствие структуры Hard Logic приводит к ошибке
компиляции, а структуры SoftLogic — нет?

```
class Noncomparable{};

struct HardLogic {
   Noncomparable nc1, nc2;
   void compare() {
       nc1 == nc2; //Ошибка компилятора: бинарный "==": не найден оператор, принимающий левый операнд типа "Noncomparable" (или приемлемое преобразование отсутствует)
   }
};

template<class T> 
struct SoftLogic {
   Noncomparable nc1,nc2;
   void compare() {
      nc1 == nc2; //Нет ошибки
   }
};
```

Comment: Попробуйте закомментировать структуру HardLogic. Возможно, компилятор не проверяет код дальше HardLogic из-за ошибки.

Comment: Всё равно нет ошибки

Comment: А какую ошибку выдает?

Comment: бинарный "==": не найден оператор, принимающий левый операнд типа "Noncomparable" (или приемлемое преобразование отсутствует)

Comment: Потому что нет instantiation

Comment: А вы теперь ниже шаблона напишите `typedef SoftLogic<int> SoftLogicInt;` получите ту же ошибку. [Test](https://ideone.com/fPtEYW)

Answer (score 1):

В данном случае невозможность создать для шаблона `SoftLogic::compare` валидную специализацию делает все программу невалидной, причем диагностика в этом случае не требуется:

> **17.7 Name resolution [temp.res]**
>   **8** The program is ill-formed, no diagnostic required, if:
>   (8.1) — no valid specialization can be generated for a template or a substatement of a constexpr if statement (9.4.1) within a template and the template is not instantiated, or

Answer (score 0):

потому что SoftLogic - это не структура, а шаблон структуры. Ошибка будет только если к коде появится инстанцирование функции SoftLogic::compare, т.е. появится потребность в конкретной реализации, как в случае с HardLogic::compare.

Comment: Сами спросили, сами ответили? Только вот не хорошо брать чужой ответ на свой вопрос на другом форуме не указав ссылки на оригинал.

Comment: Да, действительно не хорошо http://www.cyberforum.ru/cpp-beginners/thread2415413.html

Comment: @Croessmah **Сами спросили, сами ответили?** И что такого? Когда я спрашивал, ответа разумеется не знал

Comment: мой комментарий относится исключительно к отсутствию ссылки на оригинал.